# Given an element , how to erase all the nodes with the given element value?

Tags: java

Ok, I have my Node class with some fields defined as an integer for the value (val) and a Node one for a reference. Also I have a second class called listaArmada with a Node head field that indicates the beginning of the list. I created a method class called borrarEle that receives a created list with some random values and an integer. The method must search within the list for nodes with the value of the given element and eliminate all nodes that contain it. It works but only removes the first element found and not the others as well. Should be able to remove any node that has that element regardless of position.

> List: 9,1,2,12,14,2,7,7,1,10
>
> value to eliminate: 7
>
> Expected output: 9,1,2,12,14,2,1,10
>
> Real output: 9,1,2,12,14,2,**7**,1,10

-------NODE CLASS

```
public class Nodo {
int val;
Nodo siguiente;

public Nodo(int ob, Nodo nxt){
    this.val = ob;
    this.siguiente = nxt;
  }
}
```

-------------------------------SECOND CLASS

```
public class listaArmada {

static public Nodo head;
static public int size;

static void borrarEle(int n, listaArmada ls){

    Nodo anterior = null;
    if(ls.head.val == n){//EL ELEMENTO ESTÁ EN LA CABEZA
        ls.head = ls.head.siguiente;
    }else{
        Nodo temp = ls.head;
        while(temp.siguiente.val != n){
            temp = temp.siguiente;

        }
        Nodo sg = temp.siguiente.siguiente;
        temp.siguiente = sg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is only ever removing one node from the list. You need a loop to keep looking at the rest of the nodes even after you remove one. This also applies to the head nodes, as your code right now would also get the wrong result for a list like 7,7,1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE) so in the below code I added to your code in order to create a MRE. Basically, class `ListaArmada` is a [singly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) where each node in the list is an instance of class `Nodo`.

First I added method `append()` to class `ListaArmada` so as to be able to create a list. Second, I overrode method `toString()` in both `ListaArmada` and `Nodo` classes so as to facilitate testing and debugging.

I used the sample data you provided in your question. Also, I used [OOP principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

```java
public class ListaArmada {
    public Nodo head;

    public void append(int val) {
        Nodo n = new Nodo(val, null);
        if (head == null) {
            head = n;
        }
        else {
            Nodo next = head.getSiguiente();
            Nodo prev = head;
            while (next != null) {
                prev = next;
                next = next.getSiguiente();
            }
            prev.setSiguiente(n);
        }
    }

    public void borrarEle(int n) {
        if (head != null) {
            Nodo curr = head;
            Nodo prev = head;
            while (curr != null) {
                if (curr.getVal() == n) {
                    prev.setSiguiente(curr.getSiguiente());
                    if (curr == head) {
                        head = curr.getSiguiente();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    prev = curr;
                }
                curr = curr.getSiguiente();
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Nodo curr = head;
        while (curr != null) {
            sb.append(curr);
            curr = curr.getSiguiente();
        }
        sb.append("END");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListaArmada la = new ListaArmada();
        la.append(9);
        la.append(1);
        la.append(2);
        la.append(12);
        la.append(14);
        la.append(2);
        la.append(7);
        la.append(7);
        la.append(1);
        la.append(10);
        System.out.println(la);
        la.borrarEle(7);
        System.out.println(la);
    }
}

class Nodo {
    private int val;
    private Nodo siguiente;

    public Nodo(int ob, Nodo nxt) {
        this.val = ob;
        this.siguiente = nxt;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public Nodo getSiguiente() {
        return siguiente;
    }

    public void setSiguiente(Nodo n) {
        siguiente = n;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d -> ", val);
    }
}
```

The `append()` method simply appends a new node to the end of the list.

The `while` loop in your `borrarEle()` method is wrong. You want to iterate through all the nodes in the list. You know that you have reached the last node in the list when its `siguiente` is null. You also need to handle the situation where you delete the first node in the list. In that case you also have to update `head` in class `ListaArmada`.

Running the above code produces the following output.

```
9 -> 1 -> 2 -> 12 -> 14 -> 2 -> 7 -> 7 -> 1 -> 10 -> END
9 -> 1 -> 2 -> 12 -> 14 -> 2 -> 1 -> 10 -> END
```